# How to insert textbox value from form to csv one by one?

Tags: php, html, csv

My Goal is to insert the value from a textbox from a form to csv one by one.

I tried to look for answers in the internet but I can't seems to find similar scenario on this problem

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {

 //read data from form
 $lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName");
 $fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName");
 $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email");
 $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "phone");

 //generate output for text file
 $output = $fName . " ";
 $output .= $lName . " ";
 $output .= $email . " ";
 $output .= $phone . " ";

 //here "t" means tab
 //here "n" newline 

 //open file for output with append mode "a"
 $fp = fopen("contacts.csv", "a");
 //write to the file
 fwrite($fp, $output);
 fclose($fp);

 }
 else
 {
   echo "empty submit";
 }
 ?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="next_page.php" method="post" >
  Lastname:<input type="text" name="lName" />
  Firstname:<input type="text" name="fName" />
  Email:<input type="text" name="email" />
  Phone:<input type="text" name="phone" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My expected output is Lastname will be save in first cell, Firstname will be saev in 2nd cell, and so on.

Comment: What is currently happening?

Comment: "CSV" stands for "comma separated values". You are not separating your values with commas.

Comment: Just to correct my mistake: My goal is to paste the value of Lastname to first column, Firstname to 2nd cell column , Email to 3rd cell column and phone to the 4th column.

Comment: You might want to check out [fputcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Comment: You might also want a new line in there somewhere - although I would suggest something like `$output .= PHP_EOL;`